# Google App engine can not see my CSS files

Tags: google-app-engine

Google Appengine
I am working on a Google App engine project but i cannot see my css.The code just appears plain. My styles can not be seen on the html page.

My app.yaml file is as shown below:

```
application: paymentgateway
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: .*
  script: main.py

- url: /css
  static_dir: css
```

My main.py file is as below:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template



class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
       self.response.out.write(template.render('account_type.html',''))


def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                                     debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

account_type.html is as shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="formwrap">
<div id="form">
<fieldset><legend><h3>Select Country and Account Type</h3></legend>
<form action="registration_form.html" method="post">
<div class="row">
<div class="label">Select Country </div><!--end .label-->
<div class="input">
<select name="country" class="detail" >
<option>--select country--</option>
<option>Uganda</option>
<option>Kenya</option>
<option>Tanzania</option>
<option>Rwanda</option>
</select>
</div><!--end .input-->
</div><!--end .row-->

<div class="row">
<div class="label">Account Types</div><!--end .label-->
<div class="input">
<input type="radio" name="account" class=""/>
</div><!--end .input-->
</div><!--end .row-->

<div id="submit">
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="NEXT">
</div><!-- end #submit -->
</form>
</fieldset>
</div><!--end #form-->
</div><!--end #formwrap-->
</body>
</html>
```

i have my css in a css folder.

styles.css is as shown below:

```
body {
background:#E9E9E9;
}


#formWrap {
  width:720px;
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-left:30px;
  background:#FFF;
  border:1px solid #f1f1f1;
   -moz-border-radius:20px;
   -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #999;
   -webkit-border-radius:20px;
   -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #999;
   padding:16px 10px 40px;

}
 #formWrap #form {
border:0px solid #EEE;
width:720px;


}
#form .row {

border:0;
display:block;
line-height:38px;
overflow:auto;
padding:24px 0px;
width:100%;
}
#form .row .label {
font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
width:180px;
text-align:right;
float:left;
padding-right:10px;
margin-right:10px;



 }
 #form.row .input {
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
width:auto;
 }

 .detail{
width:260px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:20px;
padding:7px 8px;
margin:0;
display:block;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background:#E9E9E9;
border:1px solid #CCC;
}
 .detail:focus{
 background-color:#FFF;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 outline: none;

}

 .message{
width:400px;
max-width:400px;
height:280px;
overflow:auto;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:20px;
padding:7px 8px;
line-height:1em;
margin:0;
display:block;

}

#form .row .context {
color:#000;
font-size:16px;
line-height:14px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-left:5px;

 }
 #formWrap #form #submit {
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 margin-top:25px;
 margin-left:120px;
 color:#000;
font-size:16px;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #999;
padding:10px;
width:150px;
height:40px;

 }
span.error{
color:#000;
display:block;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-image:url(file:///C|/wamp/www/ContactForm/images/x.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left 6px;
padding-left:25px;


}
```

So, when i run the project with Python Google Appengine, I can not see my styles on the page.

What is the problem?

Comment: What does your browser say? does it try to load the css? do you get 404? is the path not what you think it should be?

Comment: Does this also happen on the development server, or only in production ? Can you share the url where you have deployed your application?

Comment: This may be an old question, but I used this [solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31591467/1665739

Answer (score 17):

From the docs:

```
URL handler path patterns are tested in the order they appear in app.yaml
```

The problem with your `app.yaml` is that *all* urls are mapped to the `main.py`, so your static handler is never reached.

So your `app.yaml` should look like this:

```
application: paymentgateway
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

Note that here css static handler is listed *before* application handler.

Comment: what if I have index.html static file and /assets directory with multiple sub-directories with many possible levels of directories? the above setup won't work

Answer (score 0):

If you see this problem only when using chrome or safari you might just be facing the same issue I had which is a bug in AppEngine returning null as the content-type for css files. Upgrading to 1.6.2.1 fixed my problem.